# Index was out of range for the first cell of the selected row

Tags: c#, indexing

```
playerProfileID = (int)transfersDGV.SelectedRows[transfersDGV.CurrentRow.Index]
                                   .Cells[0].Value;
```

I get an error saying: "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection."
I've tried to pick up the value of a first cell from the selected row. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Was there no row selected? Or does it have zero cells?

Comment: Try splitting the line of code into two lines.  One to select row and then one to get cell.  Which one does it throw the error on then?

Comment: There's not enough code or information here for anyone to help you.  Which of those indexes is the one that's complaining?  The `SelectedRows` or the `Cells`?  Are there actually any rows selected?  What is `transfersDGV.CurrentRow.Index`?  Have you done any basic debugging?

Comment: Maybe break this down a bit and assign the value of "transferDGV.CurrentRow.Index" to a variable first, to make sure you are getting a selected row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to use

```
transfersDGV.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value
```

`SelectedRows` contains the set of currently selected rows.  If you select 1, it contains that row.  If you select 10, it will contain those 10.

You need to *check to see if there are any rows selected* and *then* take the first one (or whichever one you need) to get the first cell's value.

`CurrentRow` is the row that currently has focus, and may or may not be among the selected rows.

Answer (score 0):

[SelectedRows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.selectedrows.aspx) holds array of selected rows. If there are 2 rows selected, max accessible index in it would be 1. You try to access it via `CurrentRow.Index` property, which is relative position of row in whole grid. So you get the index out of range exception. If you 
want to

> pick up the value of a first cell from the selected row

you should use

```
(int)transfersDGV.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't say for sure without knowing what types you're using in the code there... Is `transfersDGV` an iterator of some kind? Some iterators point to the end or after the end of the collection once they have iterated through the whole collection. Another alternative is that it needs to be initalized somehow. There might also be a problem with `Cells` being empty, in which case `Cells[0]` would actually be causing the exception.